# Iterate through all non-system databases and empty them

Tags: sql-server

On SQL Server 2012...I have multiple databases on a server used for training purposes.  Periodically, these need to be cleared for a fresh start.  When quantities of databases were small I would use Adam Anderson's code to remove all objects and manually change the USE statement.  With 200+ databases now, I'd rather not.  Looking to automate this process.  I'm trying to use sp_MSforeachdb, without luck so far.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance!

```
DECLARE @command nvarchar(max) 

SELECT @command ='IF EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name = ''?'' 
    AND name LIKE ''learndb%''        --we have learndb1, learndb2, etc...
)
BEGIN

DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @n char(1)
SET @n = char(10)

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) +
    ''drop procedure ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']''
from sys.procedures

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) +
''alter table ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + '']    drop constraint ['' + name + '']''
from sys.check_constraints

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) +
    ''drop function ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']''
from sys.objects
where type in ( ''FN'', ''IF'', ''TF'' )

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) +
    ''drop view ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']''
from sys.views

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) +
    ''alter table ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + ''] drop constraint ['' + name + '']''
from sys.foreign_keys

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) +
    ''drop table ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']''
from sys.tables

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) +
    ''drop type ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']''
from sys.types
where is_user_defined = 1

select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''') +
    ''drop trigger ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']''
from sys.objects
where type = ''TF'' exec sp_executesql @stmt END'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

Comment: Karen, would scripting a restore of the 200 db's be out of the question or are you looking to rebuild specific objects of each database?

Comment: So you want to drop every single procedure, constraint, function, view, foreign key, alias type and trigger from every user database on the system? Wouldn't it be easier to just drop all 200 databases and re-create them?

Comment: As @Jeff says - create a template DB with just the object & users you want to get back to.  Take a backup of that template.  Restore that backup over each of the training DBs.  With not much work you can find the existing DBs' physical file names and use them in the RESTORE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would think a much simpler approach would be to just drop all the databases and re-create them empty:

```
USE [master];
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'
ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) 
  + ' SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
  DROP DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';
  CREATE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name LIKE N'learndb%';

PRINT @sql;
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

If you have a user or set of users needed in every database, then just add that user to the `model` database.

Answer (score 5):

Try using [sp_MSforeachdb - Aaron's version](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/).

That is more reliable than the *undocumented* `sp_MSforeachdb`.

Also, it would be more plausible if you can just recreate the databases from scratch (like [Aaron Suggested above](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75997/8783)), make sure you have [**Instant File initialization - Enabled**](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/instant-initialization-what-why-and-how/).

Comment: Yes, please stop using `sp_MSforeachdb`, and please, everyone, if IFI is not enabled, stop what you're doing and enable it now.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems with your script all fairly minor.  First of all your comment at the beginning also commented out the ')' and the 'BEGIN'.  I'm guessing that was just a change you made to put the code here though.  The biggest problem you have is that sp_MSforeachDB does not change the current database with each iteration.  You need to put in a `USE` statement manually.  Here is a version where I put a `USE [?];` inside your block.  I also commented out the `EXEC sp_executesql` and put some prints in so that you can see what is happening before you run it.

```
DECLARE @command nvarchar(max)

SELECT @command ='IF EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM sys.databases WHERE name = ''?'' AND name LIKE ''learndb%'') --we have learndb1, learndb2, etc...  
BEGIN
    USE [?];
    DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max) DECLARE @n char(1) SET @n = char(10)
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) + ''drop procedure ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']'' from sys.procedures
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) + ''alter table ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + ''] drop constraint ['' + name + '']'' from sys.check_constraints
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) + ''drop function ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']'' from sys.objects where type in ( ''FN'', ''IF'', ''TF'' )
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) + ''drop view ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']'' from sys.views
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) + ''alter table ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + ''] drop constraint ['' + name + '']'' from sys.foreign_keys
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) + ''drop table ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']'' from sys.tables
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''' ) + ''drop type ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']'' from sys.types where is_user_defined = 1
    select @stmt = isnull( @stmt + @n, '''') + ''drop trigger ['' + schema_name(schema_id) + ''].['' + name + '']'' from sys.objects where type = ''TF'' 

    PRINT ''----------------------------------------------------------------------------''
    PRINT ''?''
    PRINT @stmt
    --exec sp_executesql @stmt

END'

EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```

All of that being said there is a fair amount of proof that `sp_msforeachdb` doesn't always hit all databases and you probably should be careful about using it.  I also can't help but think there has to be an easier way to do the whole process.  Possibly a restore  script or a script that drops the specified DB and creates a new one.